# Text doesn't display correctly when loaded from SQL DB

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, freetextbox

I use FreeTextBox for my webpage. And when I load the text again from Database to display on a Label, it doesn't display correctly( still contain HTML tag: ,...)
Take a look at my code below ( load the text from the DB)

```
Datatable db= excute .....;
string content = db.Rows[0]["CONTENT"].toString();

Label1.Text= content;
```

Just a basic codes , I really don't know where is the mistake.

```
Label1.Text ----> Demo freetextbox<div> just a simple demo</div><div>dnalksdfasdflklsd</div>
```

Comment: You could also use a Literal, and the Mode property http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.literal.mode.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Label1.Text = HttpUtilities.HtmlDecode(content);
```

It decode the text, and the text will be displayed correctly.